# How to change a checkbox clickable from false to true when another checkbox is checked

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to change the clickable checkBoxSides1 from false to true when the checkBoxMain1 is checked

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxMain1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewMain"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textViewMain"
    android:text="Scrambled Eggs" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxSides1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewSides"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textViewSides"
    android:text="Baked Beans" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a `RadioGroup`? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup and https://m2.material.io/components/radio-buttons#usage Especially if you're following the Material spec: *radio buttons should be used instead of checkboxes if only one item can be selected from a list.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Kotlin? Maybe you can try `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

```
checkBoxMain1.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
  checkBoxSides1.isChecked = isChecked
}
```